# RoR model with has_many relation and class_name option; symbol vs string vs class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, foreign-keys

Which type it's a **best practice** for RoR model with has_many relation and class_name option; a symbol, string or class

For example:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base

  # as symbol
  has_many :invoices, class_name: :CustomerInvoices

  # as string
  has_many :invoices, class_name: "CustomerInvoices"

  # as symbol
  has_many :invoices, class_name: CustomerInvoices
end
```

I test each code variant and it's works in the same way (apparently).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The community-driven [ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) says that you [should only use snake case for symbols](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#snake-case-symbols-methods-vars), so I'd say your first example is ruled out.

I've seen the other two methods both used. The [Rails style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide) is silent on the matter. I'd say choose one and be consistent in using it.